# How to Interrupt in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

In Java, let's say I have a GUI with 2 buttons, Go and Pause.

When I press Go, "Hello" gets printed out over and over again. When I press Pause, "Hello" no longer gets printed to the screen.

Example: User presses Go button. "Hello" gets printed out for 1 minute until the user presses "Pause."

What is the proper way to express this approach in Java? Is it equivalent to my commented pseudocode within the goButton source?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == goButton)
    {
        // while user has not pressed the pause button
        printHello();
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == pauseButton)
    {
        pause();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get this to work, in reasonable fashion, you will need a `Thread`.  This is executed in the background until such time as you decide to cancel/pause it.

This is an EXTREMELY basic example. Normally I'd wrap the task and the GUI up in appropriate classes rather then accessing static references, but it gives a basic idea

```
public class TestHello {

    private static HelloTask task;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread thread = new Thread((task = new HelloTask()));
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JButton goButton = new JButton("Go");
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");

        goButton.setActionCommand("Go");
        stopButton.setActionCommand("Stop");

        ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();

        goButton.addActionListener(handler);
        stopButton.addActionListener(handler);

        frame.add(goButton);
        frame.add(stopButton);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Go")) {
                task.start();
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")) {
                task.pause();
            }

        }

    }

    public static class HelloTask implements Runnable {

        private static final Object WAIT_LOCK = new Object();
        private boolean dump = false;

        public void start() {
            synchronized (WAIT_LOCK) {
                dump = true;
                WAIT_LOCK.notify();
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            synchronized (WAIT_LOCK) {
                dump = false;
                WAIT_LOCK.notify();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                while (dump) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                }
                try {
                    synchronized (WAIT_LOCK) {
                        WAIT_LOCK.wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some further read:

- [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

**Caveats**

NEVER try and modify the GUI from any thread other then the Event Dispatching Thread.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. How does run() get called? I took what you have above, but my run() method is not getting called.

Comment: The `run` method is called on your behalf by `Thread`.  Make sure 1. you're supplying a `Runnable` to the `Thread` and 2. You're calling `Thread.start` (I always forget this one :P)

Comment: Why is the try/catch needed in the HelloTasks's run() method?

Comment: The `try/catch` around the `WAIT_LOCK.wait()` is there because `wait` can be interrupted (via [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29))

Comment: Oh. So without that try/catch, the bool to control the printHello's could never change because it'd be stuck in an endless loop?

Comment: The line `WAIT_LOCK.wait()` will basically put the thread to sleep while it waits for notification.  This notification comes from the line `WAIT_LOCK.notify()` which (randomly) wakes any threads "waiting" on the lock.  Note the `synchronized` block, this important, as the thread must have exclusive access to the locking object before it can run.  Take a look at [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) for more info

Comment: Just as a side note, `dump` should be declared as `volatile`. This changes the way that the variable is written/read to memory, making sure that threads are always reading the most up-to-date value. `private volatile boolean dump = false;`

Answer (score 3):

To have responsive UI you would usually have to run `printHello()` in separate thread. Then as you do processing in this thread, for example, after every print statement, you check some flag `boolean isPaused;` and stop execution if it is true. When `pause` button is clicked you set the value of this flag to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your loop in a separate thread. Otherwise the GUI will become irresponsive and the user might not be able to click the Pause button at all.

With this threaded approach, you also need a flag which indicates whether or not to print out the message. The printing loop can simply stop executing the thread when the flag is set to no longer print.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways the simplest being:

You have a boolean flag, `keepPrinting` and you set it to true when you push the Go button, false when you push the Pause. Next you have a thread somewhere executing a while loop which  will print nothing when keepPrinting is false.

The threading here is really important, without it you're going to have your GUI freeze once the user pushes a button as the program prints hello and happily ignores anything else.

**Pseudo Code**

```
//GUI
public ThreadedPrinter greeter;

void ButtonGoPushed(args){
    greeter.keepPrinting = true;
}

void ButtonPausePushed(args){
    greeter.keepPrinting = false;
}

//ThreadedPrinter

boolean keepPrinting
void run(){
    while(true){
        if(keepPrinting){
           print("Hello");
        }
        sleep(5); //Make sure that this thread yields if the system doesn't do it automatically
}
```

The good news about java concurrency versus say C++ is that this will just work, you don't have to worry about the boolean being crazy and inconsistent because in java variable sets are atomic. If you want to do more than just set the variable, make a `synchronized` method that sets the variable and does anything else you want.

Answer (score 0):

what about htis:

```
 boolean flag=true;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == goButton)
        {
            while(true)
       {
            printHello();
       }
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == pauseButton)
        {

            pause();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once you press "Go," how can you ever get out of the while(true)?

Comment: when u clicks pause button, it calls event of pause i.e.it automatically comes out of loop

Answer (score 0):

Basically to keep UI responsive such task need to be performed in other thread.

There can be various ways in which you can implement this mechanism in java.
I have used simple mechanism of `Runnalbe` and `volatile` flag which ensure that thread exists when you call `cancelPrint()` method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource() == goButton)
{
  //start the thread here 
}
else if(e.getSource() == pauseButton)
{
    //call cancel here
}
}

public class HelloPrinter implements Runnable {

volatile boolean cancel = false;

@Override
public void run() {

    while (!cancel) {
        printHello();
    }
}

public void cancelPrint() {
    cancel = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do more than just printouts. Take a look at [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

It allows you to pretty easily write your GUI-related code that gets executed in the AWT Event Thread and your long-executing code in other thread(s) and pass values back and forth.  This will help prevent any GUI lockup issues you might experience.